# I am stuck on how to prove the contradiction of R(b,a) can anybody help me?

Tags: logic, symbolic-logic, fitch

Here are some well-known properties of dyadic (2-place) relations:

∀xR(x, x) (Reflexivity)

∀x¬R(x, x) (Irreflexivity)

∀x∀y(R(x, y) → R(y, x)) (Symmetry)

∀x∀y(R(x, y) → ¬R(y, x)) (Asymmetry)

∀x∀y∀z((R(x, y) ∧ R(y, z)) → R(x, z)) (Transitivity)

∀x∀y∀z((R(x, y) ∧ R(y, z)) → ¬R(x, z)) (Intransitivity)

Use Fitch proofs to demonstrate that asymmetry is a consequence of transitivity
and irreflexivity together.

[image]

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/ydJyKJi.png is the rest of the proof

Comment: Assume not : by simm : if **R(x, y)**, then **R(y, x)** and thus by trans :  **R(x, x)** contradicting irriflexivity.

Answer (score 1):

> Use Fitch proofs to demonstrate that asymmetry is a consequence of transitivity and irreflexivity together .

You are assuming symmetry and seem to be trying to derive a contradiction. Do *not* do that.

You are *not* trying to disprove symmetry: **¬∀x.∀y.(R(x,y)→R(y,x))**.

Your target is to *prove asymmetry*: **∀x.∀y.(R(x,y)→¬R(y,x))**.  That is not the same thing at all.

Just assume **Rab** for *any* [a b], eliminate the universals so that transitivity and irreflexivity allow you to introduce a negation (specifically **¬Rba**).

- │ _1) Ɐx.Ɐy.Ɐz.((Rxy ˄ Ryz) → Rxz)
- │ _2) Ɐx.¬Rxx
- ├────────
- ││ _3) [a b] Rab
- │├──────────
- ││ _4) ¬Raa  : ⱯE, 2
- ││ _5) Ɐy.Ɐz.((Ray ˄ Ryz) → Raz) : ⱯE,1
- ││ _6) Ɐz.((Rab ˄ Rbz) → Raz) : ⱯE,5
- ││ _7) (Rab ˄ Rba) → Raa : ⱯE,6
- │││ _8) Rba
- ││├─────────
- │││ _9) Rab ˄ Rba : ˄I,3,8
- │││ 10) Raa : →, 7,9
- │││ 11) ┴ : ¬E,4,10
- ││ 12) ¬Rba : ¬I,8-11
- │ 13) Ɐx.Ɐy.(Rxy → ¬Ryx) : ⱯI,3-12

Comment: +1 I checked this in a proof checker.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [Graham Kemp's answer](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/54033/29944). I am adding a proof using a Fitch-style [natural deduction proof editor and checker](http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/).

[image]

Two lines can be removed from the proof if I use a recommendation in the comments from Graham Kemp:

> Just use the core rules of inference: assume Rba, to derive Rab ˄ Rba
>   and thus Raa, which contradicts ¬Raa so therefore deducing ¬Rba.

Here is the alternate proof:

[image]

Graham Kemp offered another suggestion which shortened the length of the proof and perhaps made it more understandable to a reader:

> That checker explicitly lists ~E and ~I rules in the Basic Rules
>   column. You can surely use them.

I rearranged the universal eliminations to get this new version:

[image]

The premises are in the first two lines.

In lines 3 to 6 I use universal elimination (∀E) to replace the quantified variables, x, y and z, with the names, a and b. See Chapter 32, "Basic Rules for FOL" in *forall x: Calgary Remix* for a discussion. In particular I select names that will make the goal easy to reach: x becomes a, y becomes b, and z becomes also a.

Since the goal is a conditional I will need to start a subproof with an assumption that is the antecedent of the conditional I want to derive. If I can derive the desired consequent then I can close the subproof discharging the assumption and introduce the desired conditional.  This is done in line 7 to 13.

To complete the proof I use universal introduction (∀I) in lines 14 and 15 to reach the final goal completing the proof.

---

References

[Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker](https://github.com/OpenLogicProject/fitch-checker)

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, *forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic*, Winter 2018. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/

Comment: Eh. Don't mess with Modus Tollens and deMorgan's. Just use the core rules of inference: assume Rba, to derive Rab ˄ Rba and thus Raa, which contradicts ¬Raa so therefore deducing ¬Rba.

Comment: @GrahamKemp I'll see if I can get a simpler proof with your suggestion.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Your suggestion worked.

Comment: A **proof by negation** is all you need.  Assume **Rba** , derive the contradition, then use negation introduction to deduce **¬Rba** .

Comment: @GrahamKemp Since I am using a specific proof checker I have to follow those built in rules of that software.  I can't start with Rba and deduce ~Rba. I have to start with the negation of what I want which would be ~~Rba.  Regardless, it is still an indirect proof.

Comment: [That checker](http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/) explicitly lists ~E and ~I rules in the Basic Rules column.  You can surely use them.

Comment: @GrahamKemp I think the ~I would work. It would remove one more line.